# how to apply value of ".position().left" and behavior of "scrollLeft" to overflow container

Tags: jquery, css, html, flexbox, position

I'm trying to horizontally scroll the contents of an overflow flexbox container from one div to another, by calling a function.

HTML #href and jQuery window.location fullfilled my purpose, but they also scrolled the container to the top of the window, instead of only scrolling the contents of container without changing the window position.

I figured the solution is:

```
var currentSlideFocus = $("#select_slide_" + currentSlide).position().left;
$("#slideWindow").scrollLeft(currentSlideFocus);
```

However, the value of currentSlideFocus is only about 10% of what I expected, and the amount of scrolling behavior from scrollLeft seems to only be about 10% of what currentSlideFocus. What gives?

Does position().left measure the distance between the left side of an element relative to the left side of its container, or am I interpreting that incorrectly?

Here is a JSfiddle of the skeletonized project below. Thanks.
https://jsfiddle.net/goneZoe/sf46ea03/

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var currentSlide = 1;
            var slideLink = 1;
            var totalSlides;
            var currentSlideFocus;
            var slideIntvl;
            var slideVW;
            jQuery(function() {
                totalSlides = $('.slide_frame').length;
                $(".current_slide").html(currentSlide);
                $(".total_slides").html(totalSlides);
                $(".position_left").html(currentSlideFocus);
                $(makeControlLinks);
                $("#select_slide_" + currentSlide).addClass('active_slide_control');
                $(slideSlider);
            })();
            /* slide every 5 seconds, pause on mouse hover, resume after mouseout */
            function slideSlider(){
                slideIntvl = setInterval(slideNext, 5000);
                $(".slider_wrapper").hover(function() {     
                    clearInterval(slideIntvl);
                }, function() { 
                    slideIntvl = setInterval(slideNext, 5000);
                });
            }
            /* previous and next controls */
            function slideNext(){
                if (currentSlide < totalSlides) {
                    nextSlide = currentSlide + 1;
                } else {
                    nextSlide = 1;
                }
                currentSlide = nextSlide;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function slidePrev(){
                if (currentSlide == 1) {
                    prevSlide = totalSlides
                } else {
                    prevSlide = currentSlide - 1;
                }
                currentSlide = prevSlide;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            /* formula to change that slide when the time comes */
            function changeSlide(){
                var currentSlideFocus = $("#select_slide_" + currentSlide).position().left;
                $("#slideWindow").scrollLeft(currentSlideFocus);
                $(".active_slide_control").removeClass('active_slide_control');
                $("#select_slide_" + currentSlide).addClass('active_slide_control');
                $(".current_slide").html(currentSlide);
                $(".position_left").html(currentSlideFocus);
            }
            /* --------- generate skip-to links ---------- */
            function makeControlLinks(){
                if (slideLink <= totalSlides){
                    $("#frame_select").append('<a id="select_slide_'+slideLink+'" class="selector" onclick="selectSlide'+slideLink+'()">'+slideLink+'</a>');
                    slideLink = slideLink + 1;
                    $(makeControlLinks);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }   
            }
            /* individual jump-to specific controls */
            function selectSlide1(){
                currentSlide = 1;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function selectSlide2(){
                currentSlide = 2;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function selectSlide3(){
                currentSlide = 3;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function selectSlide4(){
                currentSlide = 4;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function selectSlide5(){
                currentSlide = 5;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function selectSlide6(){
                currentSlide = 6;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function selectSlide7(){
                currentSlide = 7;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function selectSlide8(){
                currentSlide = 8;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
            function selectSlide9(){
                currentSlide = 9;
                $(changeSlide);
            }
        </script>
        <style type ="text/css">
            #slider_wrapper_container {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: 100vw;
                left: -24.15vw;
                height: auto;
            }

            .slider_wrapper {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                margin-top: 50px;
                margin-bottom: 50px;
                width: 65vw;
                height: calc(36.562vw + 66px);
                border: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .slide_window {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
              scroll-behavior: smooth;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }

            .slide_frame {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
              height: 100px;
                flex-shrink: 0;
              border: 2px solid blue;
            }

            .slide_frame p{
              position: relative;
              display: block;
              width: 1em;
              margin: auto;
              font-size: 2em;
            }

            #frame_select {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                padding-top: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 85%;
            }

            .slider_controls {
                position: absolute;
                display: block;
                height: 66px;
                width: 100%;
                bottom: 0px;
            }

            .selector {
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                margin: 5px;
                border: 1px solid rgb(91, 91, 91);
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .active_slide_control {
                background-color: black;
              color: white;
                cursor: default;
            }

            #left_arrow, #right_arrow {
                position: absolute;
                display: inline;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 10px;
                padding-top: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #left_arrow {
                float: left;
            }

            #right_arrow {
                float: right;
                right: 0px;
                top: 0px;
            }

            #right_arrow {
                float: right;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 40px 20px;
            }

            #left_control, #right_control {
                height: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider_wrapper">
            <div id="slideWindow" class="slide_window">
                <div id="slide_1" class="slide_frame">
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
                <div id="slide_2" class="slide_frame">
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
                <div id="slide_3" class="slide_frame">
                    <p>3</p>
                </div>
                <div id="slide_4" class="slide_frame">
                    <p>4</p>
                </div>
                <div id="slide_5" class="slide_frame">
                    <p>5</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider_controls">
                <div id="left_arrow" onclick="slidePrev()">
                    <a><--</a>
                </div>
                <div id="frame_select">
                </div>
                <div id="right_arrow" onclick="slideNext()">
                    <a>--></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a id="readout">Current slide is #<span class="current_slide">?</span> out of <span class="total_slides">?</span> slides. The position.left value of currentSlide is <span class="position_left">?</span></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I **sort of** figured out why I was getting the results from position().left that I was, and instead of mulling through the CSS I re-thought the way I was using variables and went this route, instead. Works like a charm.

```
singleSlideWidth = $(".slide_frame").width();
slideMeasure = currentSlide - 1;
currentSlideDistance = singleSlideWidth * slideMeasure;
$("#slideWindow").scrollLeft(currentSlideDistance);
```